# Read json file from my local file system in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am new to angularJS ,i want to read a json file from my local system, when i try to read the file it throws a exception Error: Access to restricted URI denied XMLHttpRequest.

My code

```
var deferred = q.defer();
http.get('file:///C:/configjson.json').success(function(data) {
    angular.extend(this, data);
    deferred.resolve(data);
}).error(function() {
    deferred.reject('could not find File');
});
```

please help me

Comment: Here is a solution that uses a library called AngularLoad but takes a little tweaking - http://zacklalanne.com/webapp-over-the-file-protocol-using-angularjs/

Answer (score 2):

You just can't this would mean a big security leak. this would mean you could actually upload any files of some computer to  a server.

The only way you can do this is by uploading it trough a file element in html.

[HTML5 fileReader](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/FileAPI/) does allow you to work with local files,but only trough a file element. So the user select the file themselves

or save the file in local storage instead of on the disc.